# Cannot find module @angular/core and rxjs

Tags: angular

I am newbie to angular, trying to create basic app to be deployed in firebase.

Steps followed

1. Created new app by using following command

   `ng new testApp`
2. Run the service

   `ng serve`
3. Created new firebase project in >https://console.firebase.google.com
4. Copied settings of firebase project in angular application (environment.ts)

   ```
       apiKey: "AIzaSyDlgIDn5znKfyRiTFkKBrfe3sYCIfH47to",
       authDomain: "prjsan-f1b95.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://prjsan-f1b95.firebaseio.com",
       projectId: "prjsan-f1b95",
       storageBucket: "prjsan-f1b95.appspot.com",
       messagingSenderId: "805370873210"
   ```
5. Installed firebase and angularfire2 library using below command

   `npm install --save firebase @angular/fire`
6. imported few modules in app.module.ts

```
    import {AngularFireModule}  from '@angular/fire';
    import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

Project compiled with below errors

```
    ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/fire/angularfire2.d.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
    ../node_modules/@angular/fire/angularfire2.d.ts(2,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'
```

7. Angular version used

Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10

Comment: Have you tried `npm install` .

Comment: yes tried npm install...not worked

Comment: before step 2 ???

Comment: yes tried before step 2

Comment: is there any version issue ...which version of angular to be used for firebase

Comment: Try to delete node_modules and package-lock.json then run npm install again to see if it work or not